# Construct Conditional Expectation in L2 using Conditional Expectation in L1

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space.

Assume we have already shown that a conditional expectation operator $\mathbb{E}(\cdot\vert\mathcal{F}) : L^1(E)\rightarrow L^1(E)$ exists, where $E$ is a Banach space.

Is there anyway to construct the conditional expectation of a function in $L^2(E)$ using this operator?

I know that one can do this the other way around, but I want to know if it is possible in this direction as well. If the measure space was finite this would be trivial. Can one somehow use an exhausting sequence of sets with finite measure to show this? I wasn't able to come up with anything.

Comment: So to be clear, we aren't working in a probability space here, right?  What exactly are the properties of this "conditional expectation," then, and how does one show the existence on $L^1(E)$?

Comment: Presumably if this is to make sense then you should be able to do some approximation of your $L^2$ guy in $L^1 \cap L^\infty$ and the result should be independent of the approximation scheme, right?

Comment: If $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$ then, since $|f|\leq 1+f^2$, we get $\int f^2d\mu<\infty \implies \int |f|d\mu<\infty$.

Comment: If you want $E[X]=E[E[X|F]]$ it does not make sense to define $E[X|F]$ when $E[X]$ itself may be undefined (not even $\infty$ or $-\infty$).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes we only know that the measure space is $\sigma$-finite. The conditional expectation operator has all of its usual properties, but only restricted to the case where the input is an element of $L^1(E)$. I have shown that the conditional expectation exists as an operator $L^1(E) \rightarrow L^1(E)$ by first showing that it exists on $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ using Radon-Nikodym, then by extending it $L^1(E)$ by showing existence on simple function, then showing that it is a contraction on simple functions, then showing that it preserves limits to extend it to all $L^1(E)$.

Comment: @Ian That's a great idea. I forgot that $L^1(E) \cap L^\infty(E)$ is dense in $L^p(E)$. I guess one would then apply the dominated convergence for the conditional expectation on an approximating sequence in $L^1(E) \cap L^\infty(E)$ and obtain a corresponding conditional expectation in $L^p(E)$.

Comment: The main question is, what mode of convergence do you want $E[X_n \mid F]$ to converge in? For $X \not \in L^1$, it won't converge in $L^1$, which is what you would really want it to do.

Comment: I would need it to convergence in $L^p$, so that it is an operator $L^p \rightarrow L^p$.

Comment: Sure, but then what properties of conditional expectation can you retain? You won't have the tower property anymore, for example.

Comment: I see. That wasn't obvious to me. I need to learn more before going any further then. Thank you for your help!